# Maven multimodules w. assembly options per module?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I've a multimodule maven setup, where I'd like to pack one of the jars with their dependencies and all others could stay as they are. My configuration looks like this:

Root:

```
<project...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Foo</name>
    <artifactId>Foo</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

     <modules>
         <module>Bar1</module>
         <module>Bar2</module>
         <module>Bar3</module>
     </modules>
 </project>
```

Module (Bar1):

```
<project...>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <name>Foo - Bar1</name>
    <artifactId>Bar1</artifactId>
    <groupId>${project.parent.groupId}</groupId>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>Foo</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.exmaple</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <finalName>Bar1</finalName>
        <plugins>
        ...
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.exmaple.bar1.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

With that running `mvn package` would give me all jar/war files for the modules. But to generate the jar with dependencies I have to switch into the module and trigger the assembly in addition `cd Bar1; mvn assembly:single`.

Is there any chance to change the setup so that after `mvn package` one of the jars is build with dependencies included?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the assembly plugin to the execution of the package phase:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
    <finalName>apache-maven-cookbook-${pom.version}</finalName>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

As described on [maven assembly page](http://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/generate-assembly.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an execution for the assembly plugin. Otherwise it won't be executed. The site of the plugin may be a bit misleading as there is a section on configuration which looks like yours. But if you want the execution to actually happen, you need to define it.